# Unable to use mongodB mongoexport command from the terminal after installing mongodb database tool & adding it path to system variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, terminal

i installed mogodb database tool and add it PATH to the system variable, but still can not run any mongoexport query from the terminal. what am I doing wrong ??

below is the screenshot from the system variable windows

[image]

and here is the error from the terminal

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "'mongoimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file." when trying to import data from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055637/getting-mongoimport-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-ope)

Comment: You can check if the path variable is updated using the `echo %path%` from the terminal.